# Convert multiple Python dictionaries to MATLAB structure array with scipy.io savemat

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

A simple question, but one I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around. I'm using the `scipy.io` library to save Python dictionaries as a Matlab structs. Now, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/io.html#matlab-structs) of the `scipy.io` library shows us how to do this for a single Python Dictionary to a single Matlab Struct:

```
>>> a_dict = {'field1': 0.5, 'field2': 'a string'}
>>> sio.savemat('saved_struct.mat', {'a_dict': a_dict})
```

This sounds fair enough, and works:

[image]

However, I now want to do the same for multiple Python Dictionaries. I want them to be translated to a Matlab struct in which the column names are equal to the keys of all the dictionaries (which are obviously all the same keys names) and I want each row to represent the values for those keys for one of the Dictionaries. If I see this correctly, this is called a 1 x K struct with 10 fields, with K being the amount of rows (Python Dictionaries) I want to map. fields An example shown below:

[image]

Although I myself am totally unaware of correct Matlab terminology, a good soul in the comments told me this is supposed to be called a *structure array*. I have tried simply creating a numpy array of Python dictionaries, putting that in the `a_dict` key value pair of the code example above and saving that, but with no succes. Doing that results in a list of all different structs, instead of the one big struct with the rows representing the values for every individual struct.

As such, I am still in search of an appropriate solution for this problem. If you need any additional details, feel free to ask in the comments. Thanks for helping!

Comment: In other SO I've recommended (and demonstrated) creating the desired structure in MATLAB/Octave, and then look at what `loadmat` produced.  Or just a round trip within python can be instructive - a `savemat` followed by a `loadmat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution:

In Python:

```
>>> a_dict = {'field1': 0.5, 'field2': 'a string'}
>>> b_dict = {'field1': 1, 'field2': 'another string'}
>>> sio.savemat('saved_struct.mat', {'dict_array':[a_dict,b_dict]})
```

In MATLAB:

```
s = load('saved_struct.mat');
struct_array = [s.dict_array{:}];
```

You will end up with a structure array in MATLAB as desired.

```
struct_array = 

  1×2 struct array with fields:

    field1
    field2
```

Comment: So `s.dict_array` is a `cell`, and the `[...{:}]` converts it to a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

@UnbearableLightness has the simplest solution, but to clarify the `structured array` suggestion, I'll give an example.

Define a structured array:

```
In [192]: arr = np.array([(0.5,'one'),(0.6,'two'),(0.8,'three')], dtype=[('field1',float),('field2','U10')])
```

and a list of dictionaries with the same fields and data:

```
In [194]: dicts = [{'field1':0.5, 'field2':'one'},{'field1':0.6, 'field2':'two'},{'field1':0.8,'field2':'three'}]

In [195]: arr                                                                                          
Out[195]: 
array([(0.5, 'one'), (0.6, 'two'), (0.8, 'three')],
      dtype=[('field1', '<f8'), ('field2', '<U10')])

In [196]: dicts                                                                                        
Out[196]: 
[{'field1': 0.5, 'field2': 'one'},
 {'field1': 0.6, 'field2': 'two'},
 {'field1': 0.8, 'field2': 'three'}]
```

save and load:

```
In [197]: io.savemat('ones.mat', {'arr':arr, 'dicts':dicts})                                           
In [198]: io.loadmat('ones.mat')                                                                       
Out[198]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Fri May  1 09:06:19 2020',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'arr': array([[(array([[0.5]]), array(['one'], dtype='<U3')),
         (array([[0.6]]), array(['two'], dtype='<U3')),
         (array([[0.8]]), array(['three'], dtype='<U5'))]],
       dtype=[('field1', 'O'), ('field2', 'O')]),
 'dicts': array([[array([[(array([[0.5]]), array(['one'], dtype='<U3'))]],
       dtype=[('field1', 'O'), ('field2', 'O')]),
         array([[(array([[0.6]]), array(['two'], dtype='<U3'))]],
       dtype=[('field1', 'O'), ('field2', 'O')]),
         array([[(array([[0.8]]), array(['three'], dtype='<U5'))]],
       dtype=[('field1', 'O'), ('field2', 'O')])]], dtype=object)}
```

`savemat` has created some object dtype arrays (and fields) and 2d MATLAB like arrays.

In an Octave session:

```
>> load ones.mat
```

The `arr` is a `struct array` with 2 fields:

```
>> arr
arr =

  1x3 struct array containing the fields:

    field1
    field2

>> arr.field1
ans =  0.50000
ans =  0.60000
ans =  0.80000
>> arr.field2
ans = one
ans = two
ans = three
```

`dicts` is a cell with scalar structures:

```
>> dicts
dicts =
{
  [1,1] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      field1 =  0.50000
      field2 = one

  [1,2] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      field1 =  0.60000
      field2 = two

  [1,3] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      field1 =  0.80000
      field2 = three

}
```

which can be converted to the same struct array as @Unbearable showed:

```
>> [dicts{:}]
ans =

  1x3 struct array containing the fields:

    field1
    field2

>> _.field1
error: '_' undefined near line 1 column 1
>> [dicts{:}].field1
ans =  0.50000
ans =  0.60000
ans =  0.80000
>> [dicts{:}].field2
ans = one
ans = two
ans = three
```