# Opening subsections of a .mat file in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

Background: I am working with a professor to convert a few MatLab scripts over to python (while learning python at the same time), so I apologize for my noobness.

I am trying to read a .mat file in python. Here is a sample code I have;

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat

isochrones = loadmat('isochrones.mat')
```

Now this .mat file includes a variable that is a 1x1 structure, 'isoc'. Inside of that variable there are two more structs, 'e8' & 'e9'.

I am having trouble reaching inside the 'e8' & 'e9' subsections. They are filled with more 1x1 variables that include more and so on.

```
isoc = isochrones['isoc']
e8 = isoc['e8']
e9 = isoc['e9']
```

I am able to get thus far however I get stuck after that. When I print out the contents of 'e9' it lists all the data values inside and also prints the dtype included where can see the files inside of the 'e9' variable.

Here is a google drive link that includes the .mat file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kpZsHBtWll-HMd28zQ12L8v1ahWClCaM

Comment: `isoc` is a mix of structured array (indexing with field name), 0d object dtype arrays (index with `item()` or `[()]`) and 2d arrays (some may be (1,1) shape).  You just have to examine `dtype` and `shape` at each level and use the appropriate indexing.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542500/convert-multiple-python-dictionaries-to-matlab-structure-array-with-scipy-io-sav, I show how MATLAB/Octave structures relate to `numpy` arrays (and dictionaries).  Depending on the MATLAB side, the `numpy` side can be a rather complex nesting of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at the .mat file:

`e8[0][0][0][0][0]` corresponds to isoc.e8.one: i.e. `[[B], [V], [logage]]`

`e8[0][0][0][0][1]` corresponds to isoc.e8.two: i.e. `[[B], [V], [logage]]`

`e8[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]` will extract isoc.e8.one.B i.e. `[14.591, ..., -1.415]`

`e8[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][1]` will extract isoc.e8.one.V i.e. `[13.014, ..., -2.990]`

`e8[0][0][0][0][1][0][0][0]` will extract isoc.e8.two.B i.e. `[14.590, ..., 0.818]`

Base on what @hpaulj said, and a bit of research joining a list of lists I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io import loadmat
import itertools
isochrones = loadmat('isochrones.mat')

isoc = isochrones['isoc']

e8 = isoc['e8']
e9 = isoc['e9']

keys = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']

e8_dict = {}
e9_dict = {}
for i in range(len(keys)):
    e8_dict[keys[i]] = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(j)) for j in e8[0, 0][0, 0][i][0, 0]]
    e9_dict[keys[i]] = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(k)) for k in e9[0, 0][0, 0][i][0, 0]]


e8_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(e8_dict, orient='index', columns=['B', 'V', 'logage'])

e9_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(e9_dict, orient='index', columns=['B', 'V', 'logage'])
```

So, the data for `isoc.e8.one` can be accessed with `e8_df.loc['one']`
and the data for `isoc.e8.one.B` can be accessed with `e8_df.loc['one']['B']` which returns an array of the B data.

The image below shows the printed output of the e8_df

[image: printed output of e8_df]

Comment: What do the sets of zero's correspond to? 
Why do you have  
         'e8[0][0][0][0][0]'
when there are 9 files within e8?

Comment: Do some of those `[0][0]` index a (1,1) array?  If so using `[0,0]` syntax would be clearer.