# Python: Save Struct in .mat

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy

I have Data in Numpy that I want to save in a .mat file. The Data is organized into Packets with 5 Numpy arrays and 1 Scalar Value. How do I save this into a .mat File?

[image: Screenshot from Matlab]

I tried using Numpy Records and scipy.io.savemat, and that works for saving Scalar Values into a Matlab Struct, but when I tried to combine differently shaped arrays it raised an Error that the Arrays are mismatched.

```
mat_data = fromarrays([Data_1,      # Lists containing Numpy Arrays
                       Data_2,
                       Data_3,
                       Data_4,
                       Data_5,
                       Field_1],    # List containing scalars
                      names=['Data_1', 'Data_2', 'Data_3', 'Data_4', 'Data_5', 'Field_1'])

savemat('Filename.mat', {'struct': mat_data})
```

When I load a .mat file that's structured as I want and save it, it creates a 1xN Cell array with each cell containing one "Row" of the Original Struct, so I wonder if scipy.io even supports this kind of Format.

**Example**

```
a = np.zeros(1, 1024)
b = np.random.randint(0, 10)
save_dict = {'Data_1': a, 'Field_1': b}
save_data = [save_dict for _ in range(10)]

# This should create a 1x10 Struct with 2 Fields
savemat('Test.mat', {'struct': save_data)
```

The Data in save_data is the structurally the same as what I get when I load a correctly structured .mat file but when I load the `Test.mat` File in Matlab it's represented as a **1x10 Cell Array**

Comment: Try making a sample variable(s) in MATLAB, and sending it to python.  Then try to send something similar back.  Also do a `savemat/loadmat`  cycle to see how `savemat` tries to creat MATLAB compatible data.  It may be simpler to send multiple variables than to combine them into a complex structure.

Comment: You might get better help with a [mcve]

Comment: `savenat` expects a `dict`, not a list.  `save_dict` works.

Comment: That was a Typo, I fixed it. Yes save_dict works but it doesn't produce a struct but two separate variables

Comment: `arr = np.array([(a,b)], 'O,i')` makes structured array containing the array and integer elements.

Answer (score 1):

Making a structured array from an array and integer takes some care (`fromarrays` is best for like sized arrays):

```
In [31]: arr = np.array([(a,b)], 'O,i')
In [32]: arr
Out[32]: 
array([(array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]), 0)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [33]: io.savemat('test.mat', {'data':arr})
In [34]: io.loadmat('test.mat')
Out[34]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Sun Apr 10 08:57:53 2022',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'data': array([[(array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]]), array([[0]], dtype=int32))]],
       dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', 'O')])}
```

In Octave

```
>> load test.mat
>> size(data.f0)
ans =

      1   1024

>> size(data.f1)
ans =

   1   1
```

Earlier I explored saving complex struct in

[Convert multiple Python dictionaries to MATLAB structure array with scipy.io savemat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542500/convert-multiple-python-dictionaries-to-matlab-structure-array-with-scipy-io-sav)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Package [Mat4Py](https://github.com/nephics/mat4py) it worked!